# What Permission Level is required to modify a library with unique permissions?

Tags: workflow, permissions

Need to be able to modify a Workflow on a library with broken inheritance. Do I need "Full Control" permissions at the library level, or at the Site level, in order to edit the workflow?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that only the Manage Lists permission is required (at the library level)

Comment: I would also add that any permissions added at the *site level* will not apply since the inheritance is broken at the *library level*.